# Deploying Api Laravel and Front-end Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to deploy my application on hostinger but I cannot. I've created an API with Laravel and the front-end with VueJS. Then, I have in my server folders:

```
public_html
    index.html
    static
    api
       public
          .htaccess
```

Within my api folder, I have all laravel files to my API and in my .htaccess file in public folder I have this code:

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L, R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

</IfModule>
```

For example, in my `mydomain.com` I get data from `api.mydomain.com/api/some_url` but I'm getting errors with `cross-origin`.

Can anybody help-me how to correctly set up my htaccess to comunicate my `domain.com` with my `api.domain.com/api/some_url`?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: No answer yet? I am trying something similar. If I succeed I shall let you know.